# Debugging MATLAB: Break before an error at certain line

Tags: matlab, debugging

I'm trying to find an error in my code. The error is in a function of 3rd level that initially works perfectly, but somehow at one point stops (the function is called many times within a loop).

The error says the variable is undefined (it doesn't happen at the beginning, but after more than 150 times). Could I write some condition atop the sentence to stop it just before the error? Then I could know why this variable is not defined anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `dbstop if error`.  That [`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) command will take you to command prompt in the stopped function when the error occurs.

You can also get tricky and use the `dbstop in FILESPEC at LINENO if EXPRESSION` syntax.  For example, if you want to break if the variable doesn't exist right before the line that trips the error, say line 224 of `myFun.m`:

```
dbstop in myFun.m at 224 if ~exist('x','var')
```

Then it will stop at line 224 of `myFun.m` if `x` is not a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Type

```
 dbstop if error
```

then execute you code.

See [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) of `dbstop` for more options.

Comment: Haha, beat you to the punch... by 2 seconds apparently!  ;)

Comment: @chappjc  Hmm... didn't I answer before you? :-)

Comment: No, according to the timestamp you were first... by 3 secs!!

Comment: It's nightime were I live (Spain) and daytime for you (West USA). I guess I'm already tired and type slow. THAT saved you :-P

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are out of bounds of the array or other structure you are iterating over