# MATLAB debugging: smarter way to stop the code with an specific condition?

Tags: matlab, debugging

When I debug long pieces of numerical code, often I want to see the function variable values if something happens, or in an specific iteration. Generally I do:

```
function banana(platano)

% long stuff here

for ii=1:123456789
     % tons of maths
   if ii==45612
      stophere=1;    % I put a break point in this line of code
   end
end
```

However, this requires me to write code in the function for debugging and it doesn't look nice. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the ways is using [**Conditional Breakpoints**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html). You can add them by right clicking on the number of the line and selecting the `"Set conditional Breakpoints..."` option.

Example:

[image]

As described in the comments of this answer, if you want to set it with the command line you can use

```
dbstop in filename at linenumber if condition
```

As an example:

```
dbstop in banana at 6 if ii==454345433
```

note, that the `at linenumber` and `if condition` are optional.

#### More things

Another useful tool of the debugger is breaking the program if there has been an error, using `dbstop if error`, as show [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306577/debugging-matlab-break-before-an-error-at-certain-line).

Thanks to [@Dev-il](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il) for showing me this!

Comment: I didn't know that at all.  I've always manually placed in `if` statements and paused the code that way.  BTW, it would be even better if you could show how to do this via command-line through the command prompt rather than using the editor.  Is this possible?

Comment: @rayryeng `dbstop in file if condition`

Comment: @rayryeng `dbstop in banana at 8 if ii==454345433`

Comment: Ander, consider adding in how to do this via command-line to make your post complete.  Some of us (like me) don't use MATLAB's editor.