# How to debug program after specific iteration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, debugging, iteration

I need your help. I want debug a matlab code after specific iteration. 
Suppose the following is the code:

```
**im=imread('C:\lena.tif');   
[m n]=size(im); 

for i=1:2:m-1  
    for j=1:2:n-1  
        enter into a function  
        ..................   
        ..................**
```

Suppose, when i = 505 and j = 460, the program will enter into the Debug Mode, and then I will debug the rest of the code using STEP IN (F11)

Please help me. Please please please......
Many thanks in advance.

Regards
- Jessy

Comment: See: [Conditional Breakpoints](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html#buvvmfu-1). Or just make a dummy `if i == 505 && j == 460` statement.

Comment: Here is a Q&A on using conditional breakpoints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027454/matlab-debugging-smarter-way-to-stop-the-code-with-an-specific-condition Hope it helps you.

Comment: @mikkola it is even a dupe I think.

Comment: @patrik Yeah, also noticed that and flagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated in the comments, you can use [conditional breakpoints](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html#buvvmfu-1). It is important to point out that this can be done both interactively through the MATLAB editor or programmatically

```
dbstop in FUNCTION_NAME at LINE_NUMBER if CONDITION
```

Furthermore, you can also combine conditionals within your code and the use of [`keyboard`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) to be able to interact with the code at a specific location.

```
for i=1:2:m-1  
    for j=1:2:n-1
         if i == 505 && j == 460
             keyboard % Now you can step through the "do stuff" below
         end

         % do stuff
    end
end
```

As a side note, a REALLY useful debugging tip is to actually set `dbstop` to be triggered when ANY error is thrown.

```
dbstop if error
```

This will set a breakpoint right where any failure occurs. You can then use all the editor debugging tools or debugging commands (`dbup`, `dbdown`, `dbstep`, etc.) to go to where the real issue lies and look at the current state.

Comment: Hi Everyone, Thank you so much for your wise and helpful answer. I am very grateful to you people. Thanks again.