# How to check correctness of user written code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, breakpoints

I have a user written Matlab code which consists of multiple files. I read files one by one. If I need to check the correctness of a single file which implements a function, call it Func, then how to I check the specific file for errors? How do I apply break points so that I can see what the function is doing, because the function as defined in the file consists of variables, while I need to check part of the function using specific values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to work with breakpoints.

The easiest way to do this, is to click just left of your code. A red dot will appear to indicate that you set a breakpoint. I [found](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) an example image:

[image]

If your code reaches the breakpoint, it will stop there and you can evaluate all variables that exist at the time (most even with mouseover), as well as update them to represent the situation that you are interested in.

---

If you want to evaluate multiple lines, you can stop before the relevant section (by putting a breakpoint there) and then hit f10 to evaluate a line. Make sure to check the [documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/debugging-a-matlab-function-block.html) for more options.

Comment: Also consider adding to this question Conditional Breakpoints" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027454/matlab-debugging-smarter-way-to-stop-the-code-with-an-specific-condition

Comment: @AnderBiguri That is definitely usefull in general (like several other things), but as one you can simply change the values of variables whilst in debugging mode, I think it is not needed for this particular question. -- Have added the option to update variables in the answer.

Comment: Yes, yes, you are rigth. Just to add as "general knowledge thing" ;). Good answer btw

Comment: The problem is that after adding a breakpoint, I don't see an option to run the code. The file is basically an implementation on a function, and I'm calling this function in the command window of octave( which I'm told is really similar to matlab). I want to see the state of the variables which are local to the function, because on calling the function I just get values which the function returns, but I also need to access the values the function uses locally.

Comment: @user3676846 The easiest way to do this, is to put the breakpoint inside the relevant function. If you can't find the function (and thus can't put in the breakpoint) you should be able to put the breakpoint on the line of the function call and then 'step into' it (f11 in matlab). --I am unfortunately not sure how close to Matlab octave really is on this aspect.  -- Alternately [you should be able to use `dbstop`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Breakpoints.html).

Comment: @Dennis So you mean I put a breakpoint inside the function definition, and then when I call it I will be able to access the local variable of the function through the command window?

Comment: @user3676846 Exactly, if it behaves like matlab you will be in the workspace, where the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin It worked! Thanks a lot man! Just one more thing. What do I press to keep the code running?  It stops at the debug point, and then I don't know how to make it continue further.

Comment: @ur3676846 If you fully read the documentation from my previous comment you should be able to figure that out!