# Debugging - see used if clauses

Tags: matlab, debugging

**Problem**

I am currently debugging my code, which has multiple if clauses. As I am getting wrong results only for some input scenarios I assume it is some kind of calculation mistake in an if-clause. As I have so many of them going through everyon single is something that I am trying to avoid. I want to narrow down the range by finding the difference in if-clauses between correct and wrong scenarios.

**Question**

Hence the question, is there a way to display which if-clauses where used ? Mark them or anything the like (if I am saying used I mean the if statement not the else statement). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 3 ways of doing this.

One of them is [conditional breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027454/matlab-debugging-smarter-way-to-stop-the-code-with-an-specific-condition). You could set up some of them that would make the code stop if something specific happens. You could set up a bunch of them to see what happens and what not.

A second methods would be the classic `disp`. Just add some `disp('If it got here it means that var1>40')` inside your ifs, and the code will go printing wherever it gets. This is not recommended if you have a lot of ifs, as you will spam your command line.

Another less orthodox way would be to create an array `code_got_here=zeros(num_ifs)` and assign each of the `if` statements an `id` or index. In each of the ifs in your code you put the line `code_got_here(if_id)=1;` and you output it in the end. this way you can know which ifs have been executed. I would only do this last one if there are **a lot** of if statements.

Which leads also to the point of: if you have *so many* if statements, maybe your code is not properly structured... Make sure you are not writing your code unnecessarily obfuscated.

Comment: I am not having that many, its roughly 50 if statements on 1000 lines of code, I dont find that too obfuscated but then I am not really an experienced code writer.

Comment: @KiW no idea, it may be needed, it may not! Impossible to say without seeing the code ;) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Ander Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38433260/1306647) is right that you may wish to consider if you can give your code a more manageable structure than a large nest of `if` clauses.

However for the code you have I think the [Profiler](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) would be an effective tool for comparing the sequence of execution for different input cases. A count of how many times each line in your code was executed is saved in the [Profile Detail Report](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html#f9-26561). If you run the different input cases you want to compare through the Profiler and save the reports, you can compare them side by side and see which blocks are only accessed in the scenario that is giving you a bad result.

Comment: I like the idea, but this will only work in very specific code structures I think.  Lets see what OP thinks!