# How to stop Matlab from starting the debugger when you interrupt code execution

Tags: matlab, debugging, breakpoints

When I interrupt code in Matlab (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on MacOS), it automatically starts the debugger and opens the function it was currently evaluating. Is there a way to turn this feature off? I'm currently working with different starting points for an `fsolve` optimization and opening the `fsolve.m` file when I stop the evaluation is annoying and completely useless.

EDIT: The breakpoints option "stop on errors" is already disabled. Under the debugger preferences, turning on/off the option for opening files when Matlab reaches a breakpoint doesn't solve the problem either.

I'm using Matlab R2014b in case that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it programatically by running the command:

```
dbclear if error
```

If you want to turn it on again, use

```
dbstop if error.
```

There are more debugger options to these commands, as it can be seen in [this other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027454/matlab-debugging-smarter-way-to-stop-the-code-with-an-specific-condition) and in the documentation of [`dbstop`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) and [`dbclear`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the editor, there is an option to automatically start the debugger when an error is raised. If this option is activated, the debugger will also start when the code is interrupted (which Matlab considers an error). Disable the option and you should be fine.

In *EDITOR* tab >> *Breakpoints* menu >> untick *Stop on error*

Comment: I tried that already but it doesn't solve the issue, I should've added that in the question. I edited it to clarify that. Thanks.