# forcing matlab not to pause on warnings

Tags: matlab

I have encountered a weird situation recently: when I am running my programs, sometimes the execution pauses when it reaches some warning statements (yet, sometimes it doesn't stop in identical situations, and just outputs the warning statement). I cant force the program not to stop. when I click on the small triangle below the "run" or "Breakpoints" in the editor "stop on warning" is sometimes checked, If I remove its tick, it becomes checked again after a while and the program stops on some warnings!
Has anybody encountered similar issue? is there a way to force the program not stop (maybe using some code)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306577/debugging-matlab-break-before-an-error-at-certain-line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027454/matlab-debugging-smarter-way-to-stop-the-code-with-an-specific-condition

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can use `dbstop` and `dbclear` to set and clear break conditions.

In your case, use `dbclear if warning`.

And see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, I also used "dbclear all"

Comment: You might search to see if dbstop is being called elsewhere in program